# Where is Test Manager 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, microsoft-test-manager

I was under the impression that Microsoft Test Manager 2010 was included in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium. Is this not the case?

I can't seem to find anywhere online where it tells you which versions have the Test Manager included.

I'd really like to take advantage of the functionality of the Test Manager if possible, and MSDN's documentation on testing generally uses the Test Manager for just about everything it seems.  So any information on the following would be much appreciated:

- Is Microsoft Test Manager 2010 included in VS2010 Premium?
- If so, where can it be found?
- If not, which versions do include it?
- Or is it a separate download in itself, in which case where can that download be found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385901.aspx) that runs down the testing in the new Visual Studio 2010 SKUs. It looks like Test Manager is only included in VS2010 Ultimate.  The other SKUs can create tests that can be consumed by Test Manager, but the Ulitmate seems to be the only version with Test Manager.

It looks like it can be purchased separately from VS as part of the [Visual Studio Test Professional 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional).  There is a stand alone trial that can be [downloaded](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=57e4d51f-50d1-44b6-85fd-fc7696dddccf&displaylang=en).

Comment: Ah, yes, that appears to be the case.  In all my searching of MSDN, I never came across that particular page.  MSDN is fantastic, but it can sometimes feel like a maze when I'm navigating it!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

**Bottom line:**  If you need Test Manager, take a hard look at Ultimate not because it has more features ... the perverse pricing and promotion policies of Microsoft's various channels might mean that Ultimate is actually *cheaper* than a product with fewer features like Premium  *Get the CURRENT market price* -- **do not pay *any* attention to  Microsoft list prices.**

.

VS2010 Ultimate gives you Test Manager [and a lot of other benefits] ... you could add [Visual Studio Test Professional 2010 with MSDN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038KTOY2) to Premium to just get Test Manager, but right now [as of early 12/19/2010] **the best current market price for the full Ultimate version is significantly less than the Premium version** through one of the merchants selling through Amazon.  The **CURRENT** Amazon listings are as follows:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Premium with MSDN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038KRM6Y)  *List price $5469*   Offered price $4,989.99
- **[Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with MSDN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038KNER0)** *List price $11899*  Offered price **$2,789.00**
- [Visual Studio Test Professional 2010 with MSDN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038KTOY2)  *List price $2169*   Offered price $1,925.99

*Realize these prices were already out-of-date when I hit the [SAVE] button.*

If you needed any proof, hopefully this example demonstrates that you cannot ever lazily assume that a better product with more features is going to cost more.  It's not just Microsoft -- this is routine.  The old adage "you get what pay for" does not work anywhere anymore -- you need to check market prices and haggle as you see fit.*

Comment: Best price on same product on Amazon on Christmas Eve (12/24/2010) is now $10,000 ...  looks like the bonecrushers have taught Santa a lesson.